# Escaping HTML in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

When I'm building HTML in JavaScript I'm constantly escaping double quotes. E.g.

```
$(wrapper).append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"thingummy[" + id + "]\" data-id=\"" + data_id + "\" id=\"" + id + "_" + data_id + "\" /> <br>");
```

and, when there are many quotation marks, I'm constantly making mistakes over which quotes I've escaped. And I end up spending more time than I'd like fixing them.

Is there a better (quicker / safer / more legible) way of building HTML than the approach I'm using?

UPDATE

One rather important point I forgot to mention! I'm outputting this JavaScript using PHP. So, I have code like this:

```
echo '$(wrapper).append("<input type=\"text\" name=\"thingummy[" + id + "]\" data-id=\"" + data_id + "\" id=\"" + id + "_" + data_id + "\" /> <br>");';
```

which makes using single quotation marks a problem ('cos they end up breaking the PHP! Which is another problem I keep experiencing when I forget I'm in the middle of some PHP and use a single quotation mark as mentioned in a comment below).

Comment: In this you could just have single quotes `$(wrapper).append('...'`). You can also use the HTML quotes (`&quot;`) as well in a general case.

Comment: See my UPDATE. The whole thing is wrapped in single quotation marks.

Comment: Then use a HERE doc in PHP instead of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like this:

```
<?php
echo <<<JAVASCRIPT
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("some javascript code where you don't have to escape double quotes");
</script>
JAVASCRIPT;
```

This would simplify you work.

Or you can close your php tag and open it again, like this:

```
<?php
$somePhpCode = 1;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("some javascript code where you don't have to escape double quotes");
</script>
<?php
$somePhpCode = 2;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use [templating strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in JavaScript. Makes it simple to insert variables into a string too with `${var}` syntax.

```
echo '$(wrapper).append(`<input type="text" name="thingummy[${id}]" data-id="${data_id}" id="${id}_${data_id}" /> <br>`);';
```